# In Bankers Algorithm, with three processes, in the question of need <= work(aka available). Is the need of 1 0 1 <= 0 0 2 work?

Tags: algorithms

Three processes A B C.  When conducting the safety algorithm, no explanation that I've been able to find answers the question of how the processes are being compared. Is it the total processes added up, or every process individually must pass the '<=' operator, or is it like regular integers where Process A would be the most significant comparison?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2V2FfP_olaA

TLDR Answer: It's individual based. Each process work/available item in the matrix, must satisfy each need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Banker's Algorithm,

Every processes are compared individually.

So, In your question

If the Need is `1 0 1` and available matrix is `0 0 2`, then this need can't be satisfied. Because there is no resource available for Process A.

Comment: Okay so if that's the case... if the Need is 0 0 1 and the available matrix is 9 9 0.  It does not pass?

Comment: Right. Because of no resource for Process C.